# How to calculate the derivative of a Fourier series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, fourier-series

The solution of heat or diffusion equations with Dirichlet boundary conditions is given by a Fourier series as
$$u(x,t)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n e^{-n^2t\kappa(\pi/L)^2} \cos\left( \frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) \\
c_n=\frac{2}{L} \int_0^L f(x) \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) \,\mathrm{d}x$$

How is the flux at a given $x$ like $0$ or $L$ calculated?

$$J(x,t)=\kappa\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}$$

Comment: You meant $c_n=\frac{2}{L} \int_0^L u(x,t) \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) \,\mathrm{d}x$. If it converges then $ u_t(x,0) = \kappa u_{xx}(x,0) =-  \kappa \sum_{n\ge 1} c_n \frac{n^2 \pi^2}{L^2} \cos(\pi n x/L)$

Comment: @reuns yes you're right. I edited the notations for the clarification.

Comment: Or $\kappa^2{}{}$ if you really meant $u_t - \kappa^2 u_{xx}=0$

Comment: @reuns good point, it was my mistake. As far as I understand it is a matter of notation to use $\kappa$ or $\kappa^2$ as the coefficient, right? I edited $u(x,t)$. Now it makes the flux equation correct, right?

Comment: The derivative is linear, so you should just be able to differentiate the sum termwise.

Comment: @eyeballfrog For $t > 0$ it is allowed by uniform convergence of the termwise derivatives. But for $t=0$ it doesn't converge in general, even if $u(x,0) \in C^2$